# Making a tagged part-of-speech corpus with the help of a lexicon

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, dataset, pos-tagger

I have a part-of-speech lexicon that has two columns, words and part-of-speech tags, inside a Pandas's Dataframe.

[image: Lexocon]

Also, I have a list of tokens (words) in another Dataframe.

[image: Untagged corpus]

I want to take each token in the `untagged corpus` and search it inside the entire `lexicon`. If a token is matched in the `lexicon`, then take that token's tag and add it to another column in the `untagged Dataframe`. If the token is not found then return 'X'.

Here how I did it:

```
lexicon_rows = lexicon.iloc[:,:].values

def add_tag(untagged_row):
    tag = lexicon_rows[:, [1]][lexicon_rows[:, 0] == untagged_row['word']]
    if tag.size == 1:
        return str(tag[0][0])
    else:
        return 'X'

untagged['tag'] = untagged.apply(add_tag, axis=1)
```

[image: Tagged corpus]

I am not sure whether each word in the `untagged corpus` is searched against the entire lexicon or not.

Am I doing it right? If so, what is a better approach to accomplish this task? If not, what would the answer be?